# Conditional logic to wrap some html in Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a razor view that looks like this

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(MVC.Account.Info()))
{
    <p>blah blah blah</p>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
}
```

Now I only want to render the form and submit if `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

if indention level were significant, that might look like this

```
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) // wraps the using and its open brace
{
    @using(Html.BeginForm(MVC.Account.Info()))
    {
}

        <p>blah blah blah</p>

@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) // wraps the input and the using closing brace
{
        <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
    }
}
```

But of course, this syntax doesn't work. Anybody know a good way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ended up using a razor helper. I think this is the best way, still wouldn't mind seeing alternatives if you have a good one

```
@helper Info()
{
   <p>blah blah blah</p>
}

@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using(Html.BeginForm(MVC.Account.Info()))
    {
        @Info()
        <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
    }
}
else
{
    @Info()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @using(Html.BeginForm(MVC.Account.Info()))
    {
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
    }
}
else
{
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
}
```

If you really don't want to repeat yourself, you could use javascript to move the `<p>` inside the form if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `using` if you dispose the member yourself.

```
@{
   MvcForm htmlForm = null;
   if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
      //render the begin of a <form> tag
      htmlForm = Html.BeginForm(MVC.Account.Info());
   }
}

@* content goes here *@
<p>blah blah blah</p>

@if (htmlForm != null)
{
   //render the end of </form>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
   htmlForm.EndForm();
}
```